# c, data in struct is lost after reading from a file

Tags: c

I am learning c and i got a problem that after reading data from a textfile into a list of structs some struct entries are missing data. But at the time the data is put into the structs its there. After returning it from the function some data is lost at printing out.

The struct definition

```c
#define MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH 100

typedef struct {
    char prename[MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
    char name[MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
    int zipcode;
    char place[MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
    int birthyear;
} address_t;

typedef struct {
    int length;
    address_t * addresses;
} addresses_t;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    char ** strings;
} splits_t;
```

The parsing function

```c
splits_t splitString(char * base, char * splitch) {
    splits_t splits;
    splits.size = 0;
    splits.strings = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int splitCounter = 0;
    int len = strlen(base);
    char * value = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char * ch = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
        ch[0] = base[i];
        ch[1] = '\0';

        if(i == len-1) {
            splits.size+=1;
            strcat(value, ch);
            splits.strings[splitCounter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
            strcpy(splits.strings[splitCounter], value);
        }

        if(strcmp(ch, splitch)==0) {
            char ** tmp = NULL;
            tmp = realloc(splits.strings,sizeof(char*)*splitCounter+1);
            if(tmp==NULL) {
                printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
                break;
            } else {
                splits.strings = tmp;
                splits.strings[splitCounter] = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
                strcpy(splits.strings[splitCounter], value);
                memset(value,0,1024);
                splitCounter+=1;
                splits.size+=1;
                continue;
            }
        }

        strcat(value, ch);
    }

    return splits;
}

void printAddress(address_t * address) {
    printf("Prename........: %s\n", address->prename);
    printf("Name...........: %s\n", address->name);
    printf("Zipcode........: %d\n", address->zipcode);
    printf("Place..........: %s\n", address->place);
    printf("Birthyear......: %d\n\n", address->birthyear);
}

addresses_t * readFromString(char * data) {

    addresses_t * addresses = (addresses_t*)malloc(sizeof(addresses_t));
    addresses->length = 0;
    addresses->addresses = malloc(sizeof(address_t));

    int len = strlen(data);
    int addressCount = 0;
    char * const splitter = ";";
    char * const nl = "\n";
    char * line = malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char * ch = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
        ch[0] = data[i];
        ch[1] = '\0';

        strcat(line, ch);

        if(strcmp(ch,nl)==0 || i==len-1) {

            splits_t splits = splitString(line,splitter);

            //prename
            strcpy(addresses->addresses[addressCount].prename ,splits.strings[0]);
            //name
            strcpy(addresses->addresses[addressCount].name ,splits.strings[1]);
            //zipcode
            addresses->addresses[addressCount].zipcode = atoi(splits.strings[2]);
            //place
            strcpy(addresses->addresses[addressCount].place ,splits.strings[3]);
            //birthyear
            addresses->addresses[addressCount].birthyear = atoi(splits.strings[4]);

            //printAddress(&addresses->addresses[addressCount]);

            ++addressCount;

            memset(line, 0, 1024);

            addresses->length++;

            if(i==len-1) break; // end

            address_t* tmp = NULL;
            tmp = realloc(addresses->addresses, sizeof(address_t)*addressCount);
            if(tmp == NULL) {
                printf("Error while allocating memory\n");
            } else {
                addresses->addresses = tmp;
            }
        }

    }

    free(line);

    return addresses;
}
```

The file "addresses.txt"

```
Hans;Paul;12345;Entenhausen;2000
Linda;Hausen;43122;Entenstadt;1995
a;b;8352;s;144
as;b;8352;asd;165
Martha;Kent;4444;Smallfile;196
Prename;Name;44444;Place;1955
```

In the main function i call it like that

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

addresses_t * addresses = NULL;
char * addressFile = "addresses.txt";

char * readfile(char * filepath) {
    char * buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * f = fopen (filepath, "rb");

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (length);
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
    }

    return buffer;
}

int main() {

    char *data = readfile(addressFile);

    addresses = readFromString(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < addresses->length; ++i) {
        printAddress(&addresses->addresses[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following

```
Prename........: Hans
Name...........: Paul
Zipcode........: 12345
Place..........: Entenhausen
Birthyear......: 2000

Prename........: Linda
Name...........: Hausen
Zipcode........: 43122
Place..........: Entenstadt
Birthyear......: 1995

Prename........: a
Name...........: b
Zipcode........: 8352
Place..........: s
Birthyear......: 144

Prename........: as <-- the prename stays
Name...........: 
Zipcode........: 0
Place..........: 
Birthyear......: 0

Prename........: Martha
Name...........: Kent
Zipcode........: 4444
Place..........: Smallfile
Birthyear......: 0 <-- the birthyear is missing

Prename........: Prename
Name...........: Name
Zipcode........: 44444
Place..........: Place
Birthyear......: 1955
```

Im developing on mac osx monterey and using cc with clion. I dont know whats the problem is why the data is missing.

Comment: I've tried three times to write this, and its honestly hard to pin down where to start. From `strcat`-ing into unterminated string space, to broken size calculation with `sizeof(char*)*splitCounter+1`, and several other things I literally lost track of. I think you're *way* over-coding this, which usually happens when you code before solving the problem on paper first.

Comment: Ok but can you still please explain the errors in the code. I would like to learn what i did wrong. 
I added the \0 at the end of the strings where strcat and i fixed the size calculation to `sizeof(char*)*(splitCounter+1)` but the missing data still remains.